# looping through a list obtained from python in google line chart api

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to loop through a list send from python to javascript in google line chart api ???

```
<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
  #linechart_material{
    margin-left: 150px 
 }
</style>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">



   google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'No. of Tweets');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Good-Review');



data.addRows([


  for (int i=1, i<={{f}}, i++)
    {
      [i, {{a.i}}],
    }

]);
 var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Sentiment Analysis',
      subtitle: 'in Respective Negative and Positive Values'
    },
    width: 900,
    height: 500
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}


</script>
 <body>



<div id="linechart_material">
<br><br><br><br><br><br>

  </div>

</body>
```

here {{a}} is a list obtained from python and {{f}} in total length of the list.
I dont know javascript, so how can each value in {{a}} will iterate , over in javascript , i used the for loop , but its not working , and it shows blank page

Comment: how the generated script code looks like?

Comment: data.addRows([ [x.cor, y.cor] ]);

Comment: here x should iterate till {{f}} , and same y should till {{a.f}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to let python output your list:

```
data.addRows([
    {% for x in a %}
        [{{forloop.counter}}, {{x}}],
    {% endfor %}
]);
```

You also have an error in how you're initialising google charts:

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

`google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);`

Comment: Please post a sample data of your list.

Comment: {{a}} = [0.0, 0.0, 1.7320508075688774, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.31622776601683794, -0.31622776601683794]

Comment: and {{f}} = here 9

Comment: hey thanks dude , I tried ur Solution again , without using json, mistake by my side , it works !!!